# what does it mean for a problem to be non first order definable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, computational-complexity

I was wondering if it yields any information about the minimum complexity of its probable solutions or should it give us any intuition about the properties of the problem?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA
you may have misunderstood my question. I know the definiton itself, what I am looking for is an intuition for the properties of such problems. How different are they from the definable ones, and why   ould we try to define problems in FO
Or if you were refering to some exact section in that question please tell me

Comment: First of all, 'first order definability' is with respect to a given language, not an innate property of a problem. Secondly, questions that can't be first-order defined with respect to a given language are sometimes trivial or easy; for instance, connectivity is not a first-order property of a graph (with respect to the natural language) but I don't think anyone would consider it a hard problem.

Comment: Please put your question in the body of the question and not just in the title. The title is intended to give a brief description of the question. The  body of the question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer to my question from 2 years ago. In short, it does not tell us a lot about the complexity of the problem.

On one side, graph reachability can not be expressed by an $\operatorname{FO}[\sigma]$-formula for $\sigma = \{E_{/2}\}$ (this result can by seen by Hanf locality results or by Ehrenfeucht Fraisse games), which means that not every problem in $P$ can be written as an $\operatorname{FO}[\sigma]$-formula for some $\sigma$.

On the other side, by Trakhtenbrot's Lemma, the finite satisfiability of $\operatorname{FO}[\sigma]$-formulas is not decidable (but semi-decidable), even when we restrict ourselves to $\sigma =\{E_{/2}\}$, namely to directed graphs. More specifically, an undecidable problem, namely the halting problem, can be reduced to the satisfyability problem of a specific first order formula.

---

One the other hands, Fagin's theorem describes the express-ability of second order logik. [The theorem states that the set of all properties expressible in existential second-order logic is precisely the complexity class NP.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagin%27s_theorem)

Comment: What does "$\sigma=\{E/2\}$" mean - do you mean that $\sigma$ is the language consisting of a single $2$-ary relation symbol $E$? (If so, that's not notation I've ever seen before.)

Comment: It is the signature, the set of relation-, function- and constant- symbols that must be defined by the input structures. Here it defines a single relation of arity 2, it represents the edges of the graph, and the universe of the structure represents the nodes.